# sitecore pageeditor - On saving gets error as "please insert a destination page"

Tags: save, sitecore, designer, author, page-editor

Am getting an error when I try to use page editor and do some changes in a sitecore field.

The message "Please insert a destination Page" is coming as a pop-up.

Comment: Is there any custom field on that item? Is this problem only related to 1 item? All items? All items using same template?

Answer (score 0):

Gopi,

Make sure you have given proper placeholder settings in layouts. And those placeholders are assigned with the renderings allowed in that placeholder.

This solution is for sitecore 7 and above.

Hope this will work!!

Cheers!!